# Debug PHP code via Netbeans

Tags: php, laravel

I have setup a new application with Laravel Framework on my localhost. Now my next goal is to debug the php code via Netbeans. According to many tutorials they have asked to setup xDebug for debugging.

Will I need xDebug to do debug on localhost? or is that only for remote debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can configure xDebug to work on the localhost ..

Please check [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html) tutorial on how to configure it properly on localhost.